# How to create this lambda expression?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

To keep things simple, I have this class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of contacts = `IEnumerable<Contact>`

I need to find all contacts in that collection that have, let's say a text "xxx" in their email addresses (they may have multiple emails).

Something like that doesn't work of course:

```
var found = contacts.Where(c => c.Emails.Where(e => e.Contains("xxx")));
```

I am wondering how to build such query using lambda expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Any` instead of `Where` in the inner expression:

```
var found = contacts.Where(c => c.Emails.Any(e => e.Contains("xxx")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var found = contacts.Where(c => c.Emails.Where(e => e.Contains("xxx")).Count() > 0);
```

This will return all the contacts according to the specified email condition.

Good Luck !!